# Adding View controllers as subview in Swift

Tags: macos, cocoa, swift, xcode6

Am trying to build a simple calculator app using swift. I have created two view controller with the basic and advanced options. Earlier in Obj-C used to do this

```
[[AViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"nibName" bundle:nil]
```

In swift I cannot even import my new view controllers. But still I can declare as `var aViewController:AViewController?` and use it. But I am stuck at loading nib

I tried with `AViewController(nibName: "nibname", bundle: nil)`, but everything results in compiler error `Could not find an overload for __conversion that accepts the supplied arguments`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `nil` was the one causing trouble when I replaced it with `NSBundle.mainBundle()` it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one,

```
AViewController(nibName: "nibname", bundle: NSBundle.mainBundle())
```

**This works perfect for me.**

Declaration : **SWIFT** (**UINib** Class Reference)

```
init(nibName name: String!,
      bundle bundleOrNil: NSBundle!) -> UINib
```

Declaration : **SWIFT** (**UIViewController** Class Reference)

```
init(nibName nibName: String!,
      bundle nibBundle: NSBundle!)
```

The exclamation mark effectively says, **“I know that this optional definitely has a value; please use it.” This is known as forced unwrapping of the optional’s value**.

**This is the reason, we cannot pass "nil" as second parameter i.e bundle**

Cheers..!